# How to change path to resulting binary with stack?

Tags: haskell, cabal, haskell-stack

As I understand, building with `stack build` sets resulting binaries to local-install-root directory (`stack path`). Is any way to change this directory with .cabal/stack.yaml file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `local-bin-path` setting in your `stack.yaml` file.